# Can I overwrite table background color inside an iframe?

Tags: html, css

I have used an `<iframe>` with external src. Can I overwrite the table background color of that external page?

Comment: Can you post some relevant HTML and CSS to go with your question? As it stands it's not informative enough, help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

css declarations in the HTML page override those that are declared in external .css files. So, if you add something like this in the  part of html:

```
<style type="text/css">
   //some css here
 </style>
```

the duplicate values will be overriding declarations from your css file.

Comment: Will these CSS styles effect things inside an iframe though? I wouldn't have thought so myself but I'll admit to not having tested it.

Answer (score -1):

First, I want to ask you why you are using an iframe. Instead, you can use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which overlays your iframe code. Nowadays people don’t use iframes much as they have many limitations.

By using ajax load, you can access the child page Javascript and vice versa.

The following code may help you to achieve this effect

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="x" bgcolor="red">
    <tr><td>Vikas</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
    change("blue");
    function change(color)
    {
        document.getElementById("x").setAttribute("bgcolor", color);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```